# Why the performance of two regex using capturing groups varies so differently?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have two regex using the same capturing group, but their performance varied very differently.

My programming language is python3.8.

### Regex Description

The two regex are

```
new\s+String\s*(?P<aux1>\(((?:[^()]++|(?&aux1))*)\))
```

and

```
([\w_\.]+(?P<aux1>\((?:[^()]++|(?&aux1))*\))*+)\s*\.\s*((?:remove|contains|retain)(?:All)?)\s*(?&aux1)
```

The named capturing group `(?P<aux1>\((?:[^()]++|(?&aux1))*\))` matches paired `(` and `)`, and the content between them. For example `( abc() )`.

The first regex matches string like `new String("This is a string.")`.

The second one matches string like `a.contains(b)` or `a.getCollection().contains( anotherCollection )`

### How to reproduce

I want to know the performance of capturing groups against large input, so I download an open-source Github project [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch), which contains 13724 Java files.

I wrote a script to run the two regex against those files line by line. However, I found the first regex only used **1.6286 seconds**, while the second regex used **50.6662 seconds**.

I don't know what makes the second regex so slow, when the two regex are so similar and shares the same capturing group.

Comment: The `[\w_\.]+` makes the difference. Not the group. If you plan to match at word boundaries, add it, use `\b\w[\w.]*` instead of ``[\w_\.]+``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  It works. Thank you very very much : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not related to the nested parentheses pattern group.

The `[\w_\.]+` part that is located at the very pattern beginning makes all the difference. It is quantified with the `+` quantifier that can match any one or more occurrences of a wide range of chars, letters, digits, dots, and then there are a couple more patterns to match. When the subsequent patterns do not match, backtracking triggers and can make its way back to the initial pattern, and there may be a lot of positions to test the regex against. It will lead to catastrophic backtracking.

**Solution**

**Always try to "anchor" your regex patterns at some constant pattern**. In this case, if you plan to match at word boundaries, put the word boundary pattern at the start and use `\b\w[\w.]*` instead of `[\w_\.]+`:

```py
(\b\w[\w.]*(?P<aux1>\((?:[^()]++|(?&aux1))*\))*+)\s*\.\s*((?:remove|contains|retain)(?:All)?)\s*(?&aux1)
```

The optimization algorithm will make sure only word boundary positions will get tested, and the first char must be a word char.